# What does this input via list-comprehension do?

Tags: python-3.x, input, list-comprehension

You know when you find a solution via trial and error but you stumbled so much thtat you can't understand the answer now?

Well this is happening to me with this piece:

```
entr = [list(int(x) for x in input().split()) for i in range(int(input()))]
```

The input is done by copying and pasting this whole block:

```
9
8327 0
0070 0
2681 2
1767 0
3976 0
9214 2
2271 2
4633 0
9500 1
```

What is my list comprehension exactly doing in each step? And taking into account [this](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/): How can I rewrite it using for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your code is not a nested list-comprehension, beause you use `list` construtor rather than mere list-comprehension.
This line serves as same as your code:

```
entr = [[int(x) for x in input().split()] for i in range(int(input()))]
```

**To understand this line, you must remember the basic structure of list-comprehension in python, it consists of two component `obj` and `condition` with a square brackets surrounding**:

```
lst = [obj condition]
```

it can be converted to a loop like this:

```
lst = []
condition:
    lst.append(obj)
```

So, back to this question.
What you need to do now is to break the nested list-comprehension into loop in loop, usually you begin from the condition in latter part, from outer space to inner space. You got:

```
entr = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    entr.append([int(x) for x in input().split()])) # the obj is a list in this case.
```

And now, you can break the list-comprehension in line 3.

```
entr = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    entry = []
    for x in input().split():
        entry.append(int(x))
    entr.append(entry)
```

So, now the stuff the original line can be easily understand.

1. the program construct a entry list named `entr`;
2. the program ask for user input and convert the input `string` into an `int`, which is the number of the entrys you want to input(assume it is `num`);
3. the program ask for user input for `num` times, each time you should input something seperate with spaces.
4. The program split every string into a list (named `entry` in above code) you input with `str.split()` method (with parameter `sep` default to space). And `append` each `entry` list in every loop.
5. for every element in the `entry` list, it converted to `int`.

My English may be poor, feel free to improve my answer:)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have it pretty clear now

Comment: Glad that you got it.

Answer (score 1):

That is equivalent to this:

```
entr = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    row = []
    for x in input().split():
        row.append(int(x))
    entr.append(row)
```

You can copy-paste that into a list comprehension in a couple steps.  First the inner loop/list:

```
entr = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    row = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    entr.append(row)
```

Without the `row` variable:

```
entr = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    entr.append([int(x) for x in input().split()])
```

Then the outer loop/list (copied over multiple lines for clarity):

```
entr = [
    [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    for i in range(int(input()))
]
```

You have that same nested comprehension except that the inner one has been written as a generator passed to the `list` constructor so it looks like `list(int(x) for x in input().split())` instead of `[int(x) for x in input().split()]`.  That's a little more confusing than using a list comprehension.

I hope that explanation helps!

Comment: would it be possible to generate an array that appends an 1 to itself each time the tuple (a,b) from input().split() satisfies a condition, for n times range ? something like arr = sum([1 for a,b in map(int, input().split()) for _ in range(n) if condition with a and b) ?